# Could not intantiat DefaultHttpClient in sign applet

Tags: java, applet

I am working on Sign Applet to upload/download files. But I stuck at one point, please help me:

**Here is my code:**

```
1 MultipartEntity mEntity = new MultipartEntity();
2 mEntity.addPart("Filedata", fileBody);
3 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri.toString());
4 httpPost.setEntity(mEntity);
5 DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); //program stuck here...
ProxySelectorRoutePlanner routePlanner = new ProxySelectorRoutePlanner(
client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry(),
ProxySelector.getDefault());
client.setRoutePlanner(routePlanner);
response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

at line 5 program gets stuck. It does not throw any exception. I am not able to instantiate DefaultHttpClient. But when I run it "run on JavaApplication" it runs well and when I create a jar and sign it and run it on server by integrating in Web-application it doesn't work. Why its happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the stacktrace from the console? Do you get the popup about the signed applet? Is it self-signed or have you used some of the RSA Signed Certificates?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give exact answer without looking on code. It also depends on environment settings, version of Java, IE, etc.
In general, must do the follow:
    1. Modify applet jar manifest file to be like next:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Application-Name: MyApplet
Codebase: *
Application-Library-Allowable-Codebase: *
Caller-Allowable-Codebase: *
Permissions: all-permissions
```

2. Sign jar. (By yourself or using authority certificate)

3. Create jnlp file like below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp href="applet/applet.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>myapplet</title>
        <vendor>mycompany</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <jar href="applet/myapplet.jar" download="eager" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <applet-desc
         name="myapplet"
         main-class="MyApplet"
         width="1"
         height="1">
     </applet-desc>
     <security>
       <all-permissions/>
     </security>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

4. Add your applet dynamically like follow:

```js
var app = document.createElement('applet');
   app.id = 'myapplet';
   app.archive = 'applet/applet.jar';
   app.code = 'MyApplet.class';

   app.jnlp_href = "applet/applet.jnlp";
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(app);
```

5. Enable Java console (in order to see errors if any). Control Panel->Java->Advanced->Enable console
6. Set you Java security level to Medium.
   Add your site to Exceptions Site List (Control Panel->Java->Security).  (Not needed if you have certificate).